# Android on Device Debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to debug my app on the device.

1. Enabled USB debugging
2. On Computer Managment I can see SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface

But when I choose debug from eclipse I get: Failed to install LunarLander.apk on device '304D192E7225205E': Connection refused: connect

What to do?
Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: Have you enabled the application to be installed from unknown sources. settings-->Application-->Unknown sources. Pls check if it is enabled or not. If not pls enable and try once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if in your application's manifest file `Debuggable` property is set to `true`.
When you open the manifest in eclipse, the property is on Application tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. First thing Kies has to be Installed on your system. then connect your mobile to the system by using the USB connector. then from  right click on the project that you have to debug. first Just run normal program check whether program giving the same error. To debug the Android program takes little more time then to run.

Comment: Do I need to run Kies before starting to debug?

Comment: No. Do you have kies Installed on your system? have you seen the output on your mobile when you normally run any application on your mobile from system.

Comment: I have Kies installed. What do you mean by running application on my mobile from the system?

Comment: Just write small program and try whether it's running properly on mobile. If it's running properly then their is no error in your setup.

Comment: I'm trying to launch a sample that came with the SDK - it runs OK when I'm just installing it.

Comment: OK. It confirms that their is no issue with your setup. Now debug the program that you want. Put break point where you want. Debugging the android program take more time then running so be patient. After you debug the Program one force close option will just press OK and after that your debugging will start.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6761/discussion-between-nmnir-and-mayur-rahatekar)